# POST data getting deleted between request and receipt by server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webhooks

I am running Plesk/NGINX/Apache and have a PHP script which outputs a callback from Stripe payment service.

```
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r($_POST);
```

This shows all except the POST data. The post data simply shows as

```
Array
(
)
```

What is really odd is that if I use beeceptor.com to show the data sent by Stripe it all apperas as expected. So I figured something is wrong with the server.

I then simulated a POST request using codepunker.com/tools/http-requests to my server and the post data appears.

It seems that my server or my script only fails when the request comes from Stripe.

Does anyone have any idea why.

Comment: Assuming you mean Stripe is hitting your script, and it's sending JSON it's probably to be found in the request body accessible via e.g. `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: You are amazing. That was it. Stripe support were adamant it should be accessible via POST! Thanks again.